# Inclusion containing V and radicals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit and $I,J$ be two ideals of $A$. Also, denote $V(I):=\{\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Spec}A\mid I\subset\mathfrak{p}\}$. Why is it true that if $J\subseteq \sqrt{I}$ then $V(I)\subseteq V(J)$? I guess it has something to do with the fact that the radical $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of the prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}\in V(I)$.

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal, then $$I\subset\mathfrak{p}\:\Longleftrightarrow\:\sqrt{I}\subset\mathfrak{p},$$ in other words, $V(I)=V(\sqrt{I})$.

Comment: Umm. I still don't see how this helps to find a proof.

Comment: Since $J\subset \sqrt{I}$, you have $V(J)\supset V(\sqrt{I})$. From my previous comment, $V(\sqrt{I})=V(I)$, therefore $$V(J)\supset V(I)\, .$$

Comment: Okay. Now I see it.

Comment: Please write answers as answers, not as comments.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $J \subseteq \sqrt I$. We want to show $V(I) \subseteq V(J)$.

If you have the following result at your disposal: $\sqrt I = \cap \{\mathfrak p$ prime $ : I \subseteq \mathfrak p\}$, then your reasoning works:

Let $\mathfrak p \in V(I)$, then $I \subseteq \mathfrak p$. But since $J \subseteq \sqrt I = \cap \{\mathfrak p $ prime $: I \subseteq \mathfrak p\}$, it follows that $J \subseteq \mathfrak p$ and thus $\mathfrak p \in V(J)$. So your reasoning was correct.

If you don't have this result, Olivier Bégassat's reasoning works nicely:

Observe that $V(I) = V(\sqrt I)$ since $I \subseteq \mathfrak p$ if and only if $\sqrt I \subseteq \mathfrak p$:

- If $\sqrt I \subseteq \mathfrak p$, and we know $I \subseteq \sqrt I$, then $I \subseteq \mathfrak p$.
- If $I \subseteq \mathfrak p$, let $x \in \sqrt I$, then there exists $n > 0$ such that $x^n \in I \subseteq \mathfrak p$ which means $x \in \mathfrak p$ since $\mathfrak p$ is prime. Hence $\sqrt I \subseteq \mathfrak p$.

If $J \subseteq \sqrt I$, then $V(I) = V(\sqrt I) \subseteq V(J)$ which was what you wanted.